# Filter items from an array based on input with wildcard

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I've an array coming from the output of a command:

```
array=(saf sri trip tata strokes)
```

Now I want to filter items based on user input. The user can also use wildcards, so if the user enters `*tr*`, the output should be

```
trip strokes
```

Comment: What should the output be if the user enters `tr` with no wildcard? Nothing?

Comment: yes, nothing, it should be exact without wildcard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
$ array=(saf sri trip tata strokes)
$ pattern='*tr*'
$ printf '%s\n' ${(M)array:#$~pattern}
trip
strokes
```

- `${array:#pattern}`: expands to the elements of the array that *don't* match the pattern.
- `(M)` (for match): reverts the meaning of the `:#` operator to expand to the elements that match instead
- `$~pattern`, causes the content of `$pattern` to be taken as a pattern.

Comment: On `GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` I get this error: `${(M)array:#$~pattern}: bad substitution`

Comment: @Xaqron, GNU `bash` is not `zsh`.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it:

```bash
array=(saf sri trip tata strokes)                      
input=*tr*
for foo in "${array[@]}"; do
    case "$foo" in
        $input) printf '%s\n' "$foo" ;;
    esac
done
```

Note to the overly enthusiastic quoters: the right-hand side in assignments (such as `*tr*` in `input=*tr*`) doesn't need quoting.